# Perl print unless regex and line counts

Tags: regex, perl, printing, lines

I currently have this working sorting through a zone file for automated deletions..

`perl -i -ne 'print unless (/#$DOMAINNAME/ and \$n=7) .. not \$n--' named.conf.ext`

(escaping n is required for it to work, I guess else it thinks the main script has a n variable to be passed?)

This call is from within a perl script and I would like to clean it up by not having to call a shell to re-run perl from a perl script to do it, and having the main script do it.

Not a perl expert here as you can likely tell :)  I have tried things like

```
open (DATAIN, "<named.conf.ext");
 open (DATAOUT, "> named.conf.tmp");
 while (<DATAIN>){
  PRINT unless (/#foo.com/ and $n=7) .. not $n-- DATAOUT;
 }
 close DATAOUT;
close DATAIN;
```

and a few variants, but it complains 
syntax error at test line 4, near "-- DATAOUT"

I'm sure I'm being spacey at this, and the answer is right in front of me, but 2 days, I think the brain needs a kick start in where.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the condition in your `unless`, but `DATAOUT` should go between `print` and `unless`, not at the end of that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normally

```
print DATAOUT;
```

which is short for

```
print DATAOUT $_;
```

so you want

```
print DATAOUT unless (/#foo.com/ and $n=7) .. not $n--;
```

or the longer

```
print DATAOUT $_ unless (/#foo.com/ and $n=7) .. not $n--;
```

Comment: I somehow didn't notice you misspelled `print` and copied your spelling! Fixed.

Comment: Thanks!  that solved it, I don't know how I missed it since I thought I tried all combinations. my bad, thanks again!